# How to merge contents of multiple files into a third file in c programming

Tags: c

How to merge contents from several files (not limited no. and file name can be provided through command line arguments) in to a separate file or print in console window.

Comment: By writing proper program, compiling it and executing it. If you have any specific questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: Do You ask how to write a cat (a common UNIX program)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather easy test: for each command line argument, open the file, repeatedly read a character from the file until you get `EOF`, write said character and loop. close the file. add some error checking and return 0 unless some error occurred.  It should take less than 1 hour to code, test and finalize.